# Comparing Tail Probabilities $P(|X_1+Y|>t)$ and $P(|X_2+Y|>t)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, proof-writing, distribution-tails

I have been thinking about the following problems:

If two random variable have the relationship $|X_1|<|X_2|$, we have that their tail probabilities satisfy the inequality that:
$$P(|X_1|>t)\leq P(|X_2|>t)$$

This is trivially true since the event $\{|X_1|>t\}$ will imply the event $\{|X_2|>t\}$.

What if we add some independent unimodal random variable $Y$ whose pdf is symmetric around the origin, e.g., $Y\sim N(0,1)$.

Then for the random variable $X_1+Y$ and $X_2+Y$

Do we have the following relationship

$$P(|X_1+Y|>t)\leq P(|X_2+Y|>t)?$$

Moreover, if we weaken the condition "$|X_1|<|X_2|$ almost surely" to "$P(|X_1|>t)\leq P(|X_2|>t)$ for any $t>0$", with all else being the same, does the result $P(|X_1+Y|>t)\leq P(|X_2+Y|>t)$ still hold?

This problem interests me in that I wonder to what extent, the tail probablity comparison is invariant to an outer-source noise term. I wonder if anyone have seen some previous research on this topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $Y$ has PDF $\varphi$ satisfying $\varphi(y) = \varphi(-y)$, and $\varphi(y)$ is a decreasing function of $y > 0$.

Let
\begin{align} f(x) = P(|x+Y|>t) = 1 - P(-x-t\le Y\le-x+t) .\end{align}
Note that $f(x)$ is an even function.  Also note
$$ f'(x) = \varphi(x-t) - \varphi(x+t) $$
is positive for $x > 0$.

So if $0 < |x| < |y| $, then $f(x,t) \le f(y,t) $.

So if $|X_1(\omega)| \le |X_2(\omega)|$, then
$$ P(|X_1(\omega)+Y|>t) \le P(|X_2(\omega)+Y|>t) .$$
Integrate both sides over $\omega$, and you get
$$ P(|X_1+Y|>t) \le P(|X_2+Y|>t) .$$

Comment: I get your idea. The conclusion does hold for zero mean Gaussian Y. thank you very much!

Comment: Basically we have to check if your desired conclusion works for $X_1$ and $X_2$ constant.  It is an if and only if.  So if $Y$ has a symmetric PDF $\varphi(y)$ that is decreasing as a function of $y > 0$, then this will work.

Comment: Just asking why the derivative f'(x) is positive for x>0. it seems to me that for any t>0 and x>0, we will have (x-t)^2<(x+t)^2, so the derivative f'(x) is negative?

Comment: Because $|x-t| < |x+t|$.

Comment: Note, if you want $E|X_1+Y| \le E|X_2+Y|$, you only need that $Y$ is symmetric.  This is sometimes called the "comparison principle" in the theory of sums of random variables.